# Reasons for moving from ready to waiting in process states

Tags: process

In the following image, a running process could be moved into waiting state for **I/O** or **event** wait.

[image: State diagram]

Regarding I/O requests there is no problem, I understand the reasons for doing that. However with regards to the event I have some doubts. I've tried to figure out what these "events" could be and here is what I've thought:

- A process fork for a child and needs to wait for its termination
- In the process of synchronization, if we use a semaphoric approach, when there is already a process in its critical section we would use the [Wait operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) that blocks and then adds the process to the semaphore's queue

Am I right? What could be the other events?

Comment: I think they mean IRQ events. just like how a CPU will pause a thread while an async DMA request for IO is fufilled, an interupt causes a CPU to pause whatever threads it is running, and process the interrupt. Program multithreading and synchronization is explicitly coordinated at a much higher layer than DMA, so the low level scheduler is not directly responsible for maintaining the state of the running threads, the program is. The references to DMA and Interrupt make it clear to me that they are talking about Interrupt Requests. a DMA-complete signal is an interrupt.

Comment: The more I look at it, this is only talking about DMA. when a thread asks for data from external storage via DMA, the thread is paused while the IO occurs. When that asynchronous process is complete, an interrupt is raised to tell the CPU that the threads data is ready, and then the scheduler can put the thread back in the queue for subsequent processing (eg it goes from Waiting (on DMA to complete) to Ready (to be run when the scheduler gets to it) to Running) now that the data is available.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this image is from an OS concepts book that I'm using for an exam at university. The image is used to explain how displacements between different process states work. In my opinion it is not talking only about DMA, since the IRQ and therefore Interrupts in the diagram are reported to cause a running process to go into ready state.

Comment: It's a poor book that doesn't explain what terminology it is using ...

Comment: That *"image"* is called a *state diagram*.  It's up to the OS to define what events will block a running process.  Operations for mutual exclusion vary between OSes.

Comment: I know what is the name of the "image". And it is a general state diagram not a specific OS one. So what is the point of "vary between OSes" ? I asked if my reasoning about possible waiting events were right in a general OS. The book is about a general OS structure and so the image.

Comment: @sawdust Therefore the term event should refer to something which isn't a specific OS feature or implementation, instead a more general OS structure. I don't see your point but thanks anyway for the comment.